# flask-restless dont work with hybrid property in my models

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restless

I am create  api for our front-end dev and i have problem with objects in my model. I use **flask-sqlalchemy** and **python2.7**

```
manager = flask_restless.APIManager(app, session = s)
manager.create_api(Basic_Abones)
```

> ORM model

```
class Basic_Abones(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'basic_abones'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(120))
    part = Column(Integer)
    current_price = Column(Integer)
    complex_a = relationship("Complex_Abon", secondary=assoc, back_populates='basic')
    discount = Column(Integer)


    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name

    @hybrid_property
    def price_with_discount(self):
        try:
            return self.current_price * self.discount / 100

        except TypeError:
            return 0
```

> Exception

```
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Jan/2018 13:10:04] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR in views [/home/yozh/AllStars/allstars/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_restless/views.py:1178]:
Neither 'hybrid_property' object nor 'ExprComparator' object associated with Basic_Abones.price_with_discount has an attribute 'property'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/yozh/AllStars/allstars/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_restless/views.py", line 1172, in _search
    result = search(self.session, self.model, search_params)
  File "/home/yozh/AllStars/allstars/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_restless/search.py", line 587, in search
    query = create_query(session, model, search_params, _ignore_order_by)
  File "/home/yozh/AllStars/allstars/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_restless/search.py", line 549, in create_query
    _ignore_order_by)
  File "/home/yozh/AllStars/allstars/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_restless/search.py", line 505, in create_query
    pks = primary_key_names(model)
  File "/home/yozh/AllStars/allstars/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_restless/helpers.py", line 216, in primary_key_names
    and isinstance(field.property, ColumnProperty)
  File "/home/yozh/AllStars/allstars/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 314, in __getattr__
    attribute)
AttributeError: Neither 'hybrid_property' object nor 'ExprComparator' object associated with Basic_Abones.price_with_discount has an attribute 'property'
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Jan/2018 13:10:14] "GET /api/basic_abones HTTP/1.1" 400 -
```

i dont know what happens and i cant find the solved in google.
Thank you and sorry for my english

PS: this flask plugin work fine without hybrid property in model but hybrid columns important for my project

Comment: What version of Flask-Restless are you using? The file [*helpers.py*](https://github.com/jfinkels/flask-restless/blob/master/flask_restless/helpers.py) from your traceback does not match the one in Github, at least. The version in Github does the right thing(tm) in `primary_key_names()` and uses `mapper.primary_key` instead of inspecting attributes directly.

Comment: i am use the 0.17.0 version of Flask-Restless because last version is Beta(1.0.0b1). The author recommends using a stable version i.e 0.17.0
Thank you, I will read more documentations.

Answer (score 0):

As it seems, this is a known bug in the [Flask-Restless](https://github.com/jfinkels/flask-restless) project and not in flask-sqlalchemy.

It was already fixed on the master branch but there is no current stable version that implemented the solution.

**The root cause** of the problem is in flask-restless's helpers.py file, in the "primary_key_names" which attempts to access a field called property, of the hybrid_property object. Since it does not exist, an exception is raised.

**Possible solutions:**

1. Set the dependency on the master branch of Flask-Restless. This solution is not that good IMO, as it is somewhat temporary (future changes may break your code).
2. Fork the repo and implement the solution proposed in the original [github issue](https://github.com/jfinkels/flask-restless/issues/665#issuecomment-339108801).
3. **The solution that I chose** to implement on my side is to work around the issue on my code: if the access to the missing property attribute causes the exception, lets set property field on the hybrid_propery, as follows:

   ```
   @hybrid_property
   def key_id(self):
       return int(self.key.split('-')[1])

   @key_id.expression
   def key_id(cls):
       return cast(func.split_part(cls.key, '-', 2), Integer)

   key_id.__setattr__("property", "None")
   ```

Comment: Any reason for the odd way of setting property?  Why not: `key_id.property = None` ?

Comment: No special reason. Just being extra explicit in order to "highlight" the workaround.